# How to Set up an Area method in a C# Program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, operators

Okay, so I have just started to learn the basic of coding in C# with Visual Studio 2015 and for the life of me I can not figure out how to set up an area method using Two Length and Width variables. 
Here is a snippet from my code:

```
class RVent : Vent
{
    private int w;

    //constructor
    public RVent(double w, double l, String rn) : base (w, l,rn)
    {
        Width = w;
        Length = l;
        Roomname = rn;
    }


    //area method for a rectangle 
    //Area = l*w
    public void area()
    {

        //double operator *(double w, double l);
        area = (Length * Width);
    }
```

I have searched Google and have visited forums and I am not able to grasp what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It tells me that I cannot assign area because it is a method group.

Comment: Read the error.  What do you think that line means? What do you expect `area` to be?

Comment: That because my method is named area, i am not able to use the name area to define the area method?

Comment: What do you think `area =` means? It sounds like you actually want to learn about return types and the `return` keyword.

Comment: Like in Java, i would be defining how to find the area of two double values, I am still very new to C# so I am trying to start with the absolute basics.

Comment: It should be almost the exact same code in Java.

Comment: C#, like Java and many other languages, uses C-like syntax. Unlike in VB and similar where returning a value involves assigning the value to the function name, you just use a `return` statement to return value. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx. Note that the method declaration will also have to change, to designate a type of value to be returned (e.g. `public double area()`)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I am using it to call it in my main program to display on a console application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`area` is a method.  It's an action, you can't assign a value to it, you can just call it, and use the value it returns to you.  Currently, your method signature says you aren't returning any value.  You want to change your method to return a value that represents the area:

```
public double area()
{
    return Length * Width;
}
```

note that methods denote an action, so they are generally named with verbs.  You'd call this method something like `GetArea()`.